# How to read EMF file from Word document in OpenXML and save it

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a word document that has an EMF image file in it. I have to read that image file and save it in the system. Following is the code that I am using:

```
  var lstImages = selectedImage.Descendants < DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures.Picture > ();

  if (lstImages != null && lstImages.Any())
  {
    foreach(var image in lstImages)
   {
      string imageFileName = image.NonVisualPictureProperties?.NonVisualDrawingProperties?.Name;
      string blip = image.BlipFill.Blip.Embed.Value;
      ImagePart img = (ImagePart) wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(blip);
      GetExtension(ref fileName, imageFileName, img);
      string binaryDateTime = _dateTimeHelper.GetDateTimeUtcNow().ToBinary().ToString();

      var stream = img.GetStream();
      var byteStream = new byte[stream.Length];
      int length = (int) stream.Length;
      stream.Read(byteStream, 0, length);
      stream.Dispose();
      var uploadPath = "D://ImageFile//"

      if (!_directoryManager.Exists(uploadPath)) {
        _directoryManager.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
      }

      fileName = string.Concat(binaryDateTime, "_", fileName);

      string completePath = string.Concat(uploadPath, fileName);

      using(var fileStream = new FileStream(completePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {

        // Write bytestream to disk
        fileStream.Write(byteStream, 0, length);
        fileStream.Close();
      }
    }
  }
```

The saved file when being open says the file is damaged. Can you guide what is it that I am doing wrong or is there an easier way to save or convert EMF file as png?

Please note this code works for other formats i-e. png, jpeg, bmp etc but not EMF

Comment: `stream.Read(byteStream, 0, length);` <-- You need to call this in a loop and check the return-value until it's fully loaded. That said, you don't need your `byte[] byteStream` (which is not a stream...). You should be able to use `CopyTo` directly from `img.GetString()`s `Stream` to the `filetream`.

Comment: please note that above solution works for other image types but not EMF'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually changed the way it reads the stream and it worked for me.

```
  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(completePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var stream = img.GetStream();
                        stream.CopyTo(ms);
                        ms.WriteTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogHelper.Log(ex.Message, LogLevel.Warning);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Creating an intermediate MemoryStream is useless and eats memory. You have 3 streams here while you only need 2. And you should credit Dai who pointed you at streams issue.